# NodeJS - set http server request listener after server creation

Tags: node.js

In NodeJS, generally, you would create a HTTP server like this:

```js
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = // create listener, e.g. with express()
const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

My question is, is it possible to defer the setting of the request listener to a later point in time (preferably even after the server is already listening)?

I want something like this:

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(8080);

const requestListener = // create listener, e.g. with express()
server.setRequestListener(requestListener);
```

Obviously, I could fairly easily create such functionality be inheriting from the HTTP server class, but I was curious whether NodeJS provides a builtin way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Node.js documentation says about the `http.createServer()` function `requestListener` parameter:

> The `requestListener` is a function which is automatically added to the
> `request` event.

Looking further at the actual code for `createServer()` - it is actually all it does with this parameter.

So you can get similar behaviour with just manually adding the listener after creating the server.

```
server.on('request', requestListener)
```

It should work just fine as long as you set it before a request comes in.